# Calcular cantidad de números negativos de un array en una función de JS

Tags: javascript

Hola necesito ayuda para calcular mediante una función cuantos números hay negativos en un array JS

PROBLEMA: JINN está encargado de revisar n sables de luz y contabilizar la cantidad de
sables que tienen energía negativa.

Ejemplo: para la entrada {2,4,-8,5,-6} la cantidad de
sables defectuosos con energía negativa fue de 2
sables.

Este es el código.

```
let cantidad = (numeros) => ≤{
  let numeros = [2,4,-8,5,-6];
  let negativo;
  for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
     if (numeros > 0) {
          positivo ++;
     }
     console.log("la cantidad de sables con energia negativa fue de: " + negativo);        
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr obtener la cantidad de número negativos en un array puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
function negativeNumbers(arr) {
  let negativos = 0;
  arr.forEach(num => {
      if (num < 0) negativos++;
  });
  return negativos;
}
```

Para usarlo:

```js
let arr1 = [2,4,-8,5,-6];
let arr2 = [-5,8,10,-10,-6];

console.log("Números negativos arr1: ", negativeNumbers(arr1));
console.log("Números negativos arr2: ", negativeNumbers(arr2));

function negativeNumbers(arr) {
  let negativos = 0;
  arr.forEach(num => {
    if (num < 0) negativos++;
  });
  return negativos;
}
```

### Explicación

Básicamente recorremos el array y por cada elemento preguntamos si es menor a cero.

Si lo es, incrementamos un contador llamado `negativos` que está inicializado en cero.

Si no es menor a cero, no hacemos nada.

De esta forma recorremos todo el arreglo y obtenemos la cantidad de números negativos.

Si no hay ningún número negativo, el contador `negativos` va a quedar en cero y devolveremos el valor cero.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Si te fue de ayuda considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

La forma más sencilla de lograr lo que quieres es utilizando `filter` para filtrar solo los números negativos y luego obtener la longitud del array obtenido.

```js
function contarNegativos(arr) {
  return arr.filter(x => x < 0).length
}

// Ejemplo
console.log(contarNegativos([2, 4, -8, 5, -6])); // Retorna 2
```